# I can't indentify resume label and upload resume

Tags: python, selenium

I can't indentify resume label and upload resume for this label

```html
<label for="rh_resume_upload_file" style="outline: blue dashed 2px;" class=""> </label>
```

url:https://www.roberthalf.com/job/toms-river-nj/marketing-assistant/02760-9501226436/apply?referUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucm9iZXJ0aGFsZi5jb20vam9icy9RQQ==

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to upload the resume ?

Comment: yes i want to upload resume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<input>` tag rather then `<label>` to upload the file.

Try this :

First you need to click on that label to enable the file browse option :

```
driver.find_element_by_id('file-link').click()
```

Then use sendkeys to upload file :

```
file_element = driver.find_element_by_id('rh_resume_upload_file')
file_element.send_keys( "your file path here" )
```